# Measure theory showing integral of non-negative function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:(\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow(\mathbb{R},B(\mathbb{R}))$ be a non-negative function and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f d \lambda < \infty$. $F:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, F(x):= \int_{(- \infty, x)}f d \lambda , \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Where $d \lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure

Show that $F$ is continuous for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Attempt:

I want to argue by sequential continuity. Therefore I want to show $x_{n} \rightarrow x \Rightarrow F(x_{n}) \rightarrow F(x)$. Suppose $x_{n} \rightarrow x$ then $F(x_{n}) = \int_{(- \infty, x_{n})} f d \lambda$. But since $x_{n} \rightarrow x$ then $F(x_{n} \rightarrow F(x) = \int_{(- \infty, x)}f d \lambda$.

This seems incorrect and I am missing steps.

Comment: Saying "since $x_n\to x$, $F(x_n)\to F(x)$ is more or less proving that $F$ is continuous by simply stating that it's continuous. Hint for how to _prove_ $F(x_n)\to F(x)$: dominated convergence.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I am trying to apply dominated convergence so I need a sequence of functions that converges pointwise and this function needs to be dominated by another function. Can I take $x_{n} \rightarrow x$ as my sequence of functions? Then say this is bounded (since $f$ is bounded?). I am then getting confused how I can relate this to get something for $F(x_{n}) \rightarrow F(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a well known theorem that implies your result: For every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is $\delta > 0$ such that $\lambda(A) \leq \delta \implies \int_{A}f\,d\lambda \leq \varepsilon$.

Proof: Let $\varepsilon > 0$. For measurable $A$ and $M > 0$,
$$\int_{A}f\,d\lambda = \int_{A}\min(f, M)\,d\lambda + \int_{A}(f - \min(f, M))\,d\lambda \leq M\lambda(A) + \int (f - \min(f, M))\,d\lambda.$$
Now by DCT, there is $M$ such that $\int (f - \min(f, M))\,d\lambda \leq \varepsilon$. So for $\delta = \varepsilon/M$,
$$\lambda(A) \leq \delta \implies \int_{A}f\,d\lambda \leq 2\varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 0):

Write
$$
F(x)=\int f1_{(-\infty,x]}\,d\lambda.
$$
Now, if $x_n\to x$, then $f1_{(\infty,x_n]}\to f1_{(\infty,x]}$ a.e. (note that $\lambda(\{x\})=0$). Finally,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f1_{(-\infty,x_n]}\,d\lambda=\int f1_{(-\infty,x]}\,d\lambda.
$$

Comment: _Why_ is $\lim\int=\int\lim$ here????

Comment: @d.k.o. Is this applying the Dominated Convergence Theorem? If so, how do we show that the $x_{n}$ is bounded?

Comment: @learningmathematics Each $f1_{(-\infty,x_n]}$ is dominated by $f$, and $f$ is integrable. Note that we apply the DCT using the sequence of functions $\{g_n:= f1_{(-\infty, x_n]}\}$...